# Authenticate against ActiveDirectory

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, active-directory, iprincipal

I did a little Googling and I came accross this promising code

```
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext pc = new System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN")
// validate the credentials 
bool validatedOnDomain = pc.ValidateCredentials(userName, tb.Text.ToString());
```

userName is initialized as the Windows login name. It's also a string
tb.Text.ToString() is the textbox that is being used for typing the password

Updated code and it's working. Thanks all

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.aspx) says that PrincipalContext can use two arguments

Comment: Hmm... did you add a reference to the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` assembly, and a suitable `using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;` clause at the top of your source code file? The `PrincipalContext` class shouldn't be coming from your `TestAD` namespace, really .....

Comment: I forgot to add the assemblies. Thanks! That cleared the 2nd error but produced an unusual error.

Comment: That Error #1 still seems to indicate that you have a `PrincipalContext` class in your own `TestAD` namespace - that one might not have the same constructors as the "real" one from `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to figure out this code.. This is working perfectly in my project.

```
public bool  ValidateUser(string varDomain, string varUserName, string varPwd)
    {
        Boolean isValidUser;
        using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, varDomain))
        {
            isValidUser = pc.ValidateCredentials(varUserName, varPwd);
        }
        return isValidUser;

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

> type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

Means that you need to change your code to:

```
PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN");

// validate the credentials 
bool validatedOnDomain = pc.ValidateCredentials(userName, tb.Text.ToString());
```

Basically it's just telling you that you cannot use a `PrincipalContext` in a `using` statement, because `PrincipalContext` does not implement the interface called `IDisposable`.

**EDIT**
As `marc_s` has pointed out below, the `PrincipalContext` you are using is not the right one. It seems to live in your own namespace. You should be using that from [`System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339842.aspx).

Comment: [Actually - it does implement `IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.aspx) - I'm thinking he's recreated the `PrincipalContext` from the S.DS.AM namespace in his own code (`TestAD.PrincipalContext.....`)

Comment: how do you do that? I have the Using statements on top to import the classes I need.